# Smarty math foreach sum

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, sum, smarty

How to sum all values off foreach?

My code:

```
 {foreach from=$tasks key=tasknum item=task name=foo}
   <p>{$task.porcent}</p>
   {assign var="quant" value="`$smarty.foreach.foo.total`"}
 {/foreach}

 {$quant}
```

Objective:

Get the total number of percentage. Sum all `{$task.porcent}` of `foreach`
and divide by the amount of foreach `{$quant}`.

With sum: `{$sum_all_foreach / $quant}`

Result: Percentage total

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add them inside your foreach loop and divide it by `{$tasks|@count}` or `$smarty.foreach.foo.total` afterwards:

```
{foreach from=$tasks key=tasknum item=task name=foo}
   <p>{$task.porcent}</p>
   {assign var="sum_all_foreach" value=$sum_all_foreach+$task.percent}
{/foreach}
{assign var="result" value=$sum_all_foreach/$smarty.foreach.foo.total}
```

Or you can do all this in PHP when making the array.

Comment: GOOOD working bro! Very thankx! works fine... Thank u very much!